# Excel Cell Contents by Column and Row

Tags: excel, cell, spreadsheet

Hello I am hoping for some help with Excel.

I have a 2 sheets.
Sheet 1 (calc) has a cell J10 for what is returned from sheet 2 (cellvalues).
There is a number in M10 on sheet 1, i.e the number 3.. (it changes)

I would like the value of sheet2 column O and the row 3(from M10).

I have tried various functions but just cant seem to get it right
I guess what I want in J10 would be something like:
=CELL("contents",sheet("cellvalues"),column("O"),row(calc(M10)))

Please can someone help me with the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I found my Answer

=INDEX(CellValues!O1:O24,M10)

It uses a range of cells rather than a column